# GXT - Can't reach onscroll event handler on text area

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I'm trying to have an handler on Text Area(gxt) to get to know when user reach the top of text area.

```
TextArea logTextArea = new TextArea();
logTextArea.setReadOnly(true);
logTextArea.addDomHandler(new ScrollHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
        InputElement textAreaElement = logTextArea.getCell().getInputElement(logTextArea.getElement());
        int scrollTop = textAreaElement.getScrollTop();
    }
}, ScrollEvent.getType());

VerticalLayoutContainer dataContainer = new VerticalLayoutContainer();

HorizontalLayoutContainer secondRow = new HorizontalLayoutContainer();
secondRow.add(logTextArea, new HorizontalLayoutData(1, 1, new Margins(5, 10, 5, 10)));

dataContainer.add(secondRow, new VerticalLayoutData(1, 0.5));

add(dataContainer);//this class extends ContentPanel
```

This handler is never called on scroll, but I also tried with a lot of other events, like mouseover, mousewhell, mouseclick ... and all of these events worked. Can somebody help with any idea?

Comment: Can you show how you are using the textarea, how you are attaching it to the rest of the widgets?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks - another guess, since that was proven wrong: can you show the fully qualified classname for ScrollEvent, i.e. what it says in the import statement?

Comment: com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ScrollEvent

Comment: That's the right one too. Going to be hard to say without more context, etc. I'll try to run the same code a little later and confirm that it does work. Only other thing I can think of - how do you know that the handler isn't called - you don't have it doing anything, just reading values and then throwing them away?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using breakpoints or sysout :)) the onScroll method is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, scroll event will not work in cell based widgets out of the box if the event's target and the widget are not the same elements.
And GXT's TextArea is a widget that has such DOM structure.

That's all because scroll event is a "non bubbling" event.
AFAIK, GWT widgets, that uses cells, have a special handling for non bubbling events to be dispatched through GWT events system.
And the list of types of supporting non bubbling events are too short and limited to `focus`, `blur`, `load` and `error` events.
See `CellBasedWidgetImplStandard` class for details.

**First solution**, that I may suggest, is to explicitly assign onscroll handler for textarea.
For example:

```
Event.sinkEvents(textAreaElement, Event.getEventsSunk(textAreaElement) | Event.ONSCROLL);
```

here `textAreaElement` - is the textarea DOM element.

But this should be done every time when the cell rerenders its content (e.g. when setValue method called for TextArea widget).

**Other solution** is a bit hacky and uses private api implementation, but could be applied only once to cell based widget. You can do the same things as done in `CellBasedWidgetImplStandard.sinkEvent(Widget, String)` e.g. :

```
WidgetHelper.sinkEvent(logTextArea.getElement(), BrowserEvents.SCROLL);
```

where `WidgetHelper` may looks like this:

```
public class WidgetHelper {
    public static void sincEvent(Element element, String typeName){
        element.setAttribute("__gwtCellBasedWidgetImplDispatching" + typeName, "true");
        sinkEvent0(element, typeName);
    }

    private static native void sinkEvent0(Element element, String typeName) /*-{
        element.addEventListener(typeName,
                        @com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBasedWidgetImplStandard::dispatchNonBubblingEvent, true);
    }-*/;
}
```

Probably, this is a subject to create an issue in GWT project.